# Automatically set a virtual field in an Ecto.Schema on an Ecto.Query

Tags: elixir, ecto

In [this talk](https://youtu.be/YQxopjai0CU?t=1616) at the linked time the speaker describes how to automatically set a field in an Ecto.Schema based on a virtual field by piping the changeset through a conversion function like this:

```
defmodule MusicDb.Track do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "tracks" do
    field :title, :string
    field :duration, :integer
    field :duration_string, :string, virtual: true

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(track, attrs) do
    track
    |> validate...
    |> convert_duration_string
  end
end
```

This is used to convert a user input of 3:25 to 205 for example.

How do I do the other direction? When I query a `Track` from the `Repo` the virtual field `duration_string` is `nil`. How do I install a function to automatically calculate and set the virtual field when a schema of a certain struct is queried?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you need it, you could add any such calculated fields to your serializer (e.g. `defimpl Jason.Encoder`), or, you could define the necessary decorations in an abstraction module (e.g. in a Phoenix context).  This discussion from the Elixir forum may be relevant: https://elixirforum.com/t/computed-fields-for-an-ecto-model/3537/12